# set pr_set_dumpable value to any apk on android device

Tags: adb, kernel

I am trying to debug sigsegv errors in different apk files and found that many apps disable dumping the logs by setting prctl(pr_set_dumpable,0). Is there any way to get around this and get the complete log data? 
PS: I dont have source code for any of the applications